# How Nuxtjs auth module works exactly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, frontend, nuxt.js

I was actually trying to integrate the Nuxtjs auth module into my project but I can not understand how auth module actually works. If anyone helps me with this concept it will be very helpful for me. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, "how does it work" type of questions are not allowed on SO. Also, your question is quite broad. What do you not understand here? The documentation is quite explanatory, on top of the given video. The basic idea is mainly that the module will connect to some external backend, where it can double check user's credentials and let the user pass (or not). This is done via a middleware on the client side (your Nuxt app). At the end, it's regular authentication flow, nothing related to the module itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The auth module uses various methods to authenticate users.
You can integrate a project that you have developed using nuxtjs using one of the items supported in the auth package and perform authentication and authorization operations on your project. For example, you can use this module and Laravel project as backend to handle the authentication discussion in your project.

In fact, your question was very general, I suggest you read the main documentation of the module from the link below.
https://auth.nuxtjs.org/